# github pages not building when uploading a website

Tags: r, git, github, r-markdown

**Step 1:** I create a new repository on my github and save the link:

**Step 2:** I create a new project

File -> Create Project -> Version Control -> Git

Fill in the details:

```
Repository URL: Taken from the new repository on my github
Project directory name: USER.github.io
Create project as subdirectory of: ~
```

**Step 3:** I create the blogdown website on my RStudio desktop

```
install.packages("blogdown")
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
```

**Step 4:** I use `blogdown::build_site()` to build the site where I can access it here `http://127.0.0.1:4321/.` I also run `blogdown::serve_site()`.

**Step 5:** I now want to upload these files to my github

So in RStudio I select `git` -> `Shell`. I run the following:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "commit operation"
git push --force
```

Now I have all my files uploaded to github. I can make the modifications to the R markdown files in my RStudio and push them to github.

Based on the steps I have stated, where am I going wrong?

I go to my github repository and click settings, scroll down to github pages and see:

> Your site is having problems building: Unable to build page. Please
>   try again later.

EDIT:

I added a URL to the github pages section in settings

> Source Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master
>   branch.

So that works, but when I go to my website link or github page `USER.github.io` I get a 404 Site not found message.

EDIT: I think it is something to do witht he `public` folder and that I should only push to github this public folder or set the website to only read this public folder.

On github it stats `User pages must be built from the master branch.` - which I think the master branch is unreadable.

https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/deployment/

Comment: Please have a look at this section in the manual: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html. In particular, github pages doesn't support hugo and you need to create a hidden file named `.nojekyll` in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my website simply by copying the home directory and drop it in the netlify. However, I edited the .toml file as explained [here](https://github.com/lcolladotor) to include on top of it the following 2 parameters:

relativeurls = true
canonifyurls = false

It is now working perfectly.